# Can't update/change field values in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

theoretically I'll show you the code that works, I mean, it makes sense but I can not get no change in the table! : \

so, here is the code:

```
else if ($mode == 'password') {
    $generated_password = substr(md5(rand(999,999999)), 0, 8);
    change_password($user_data['user_id'],$generated_password);         
    update_user($user_data['user_id'], array('password_recover' => '1'));
    email($email, 'Your new password', "Hi," . $user_data['nome'] . " \n\nYour new password is: " . $generated_password . "");
}
```

Functions:

```
function update_user($user_id,$update_data){
    $update = array();     
    array_walk($update_data, 'array_sanitize'); 
    foreach($update_data as $field => $data) {
            $update[]='`' .$field. '`=\'' .$data . '\'';
    }
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET " . implode(', ',$update) . "WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
}

function change_password($user_id,$password) {
    $user_id = (int) $user_id;
    $password = md5($password);

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = '$password' WHERE user_id = $user_id");
}
```

I have not even written the email function because that works. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add some kind of error handling to your code. At least add `or die('Error:  '.mysql_error())` after each `mysql_query()` to at least get some idea of what went wrong when the queries are executed.

And if you just take code from somewhere and don't really understand what it does, don't be surprised, if it doesn't do what you want it to do.